# How to release text input focus to previous window's input box? (For example, chrome search bar)

Tags: flutter, desktop

I have searched a lot can't found a way to do this. here is what I want:

I have a searchBar:

[image]

Which is, on PC, I want implement, when my app (the searchBar) input submitted,

the focus auto release and to previous window (for example, people might previous using chrome, wechat etc.)

then I will paste some words from Clipboard to previous PC window.

Is there a way to implement on flutter?